# marking the local minima/maxima of a graph using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm doing some mathematical optimization here, and I would like to know how I can mark a certain point or a list of points in a plotted graph (the local minima and maxima in my situation) using matplotlib.
here is the code:

```
# Import libraries
% matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# (x, y) coordinates
x = np.linspace(-5, 3, 50)
y = (x**3 + 3*x**2 - 6*x - 8)/4

# Tangent line
def f(a):
    return (a**3 + 3*a**2 - 6*a - 8)/4
def df(a):
    return 3/2 * ((1/2)*a**2 + a - 1)
def tangent(x, a):
    return f(a) + df(a) * (x - a)

# plotting the cubic function
# plotting a vertical line passing through the local maxima
# plotting a vertical line passing through the local minima
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.axvline(x = - np.sqrt(3) - 1, color = 'r', linestyle = '--') 
plt.axvline(x = np.sqrt(3) - 1, color = 'r', linestyle = '--')
plt.plot(x[0:30], tangent(x[0:30], - np.sqrt(3) - 1), 'r')
plt.plot(x[20:50], tangent(x[20:50], np.sqrt(3) - 1), 'r')
plt.title("Local minima and maxima of a cubic function")
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
```

and this is the output code:
[image]

As you can see there are two tangent lines and two vertical lines passing through the local minima and local maxima of the cubic function when I just want two points specifying the local minima and maxima of the plotted graph.

Comment: So you have the x-value from axvline and the y-value from your tangent, but you can't [plot a marker with this (x,y) pair](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter)?

Comment: What a massive mistake I made, Thanks @Mr. T, I'm embarrassed.